Ubuntu / WordPress / PHP files? got an error
I have Ubuntu 18.04, with WordPress Apache, and PHP 7.4 / website works great, but I want to update/upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.
I installed 22.04 on new server, installed Apache, PHP. etc.... the issue is. I restored the website on Ubuntu, but when I start the service, I get an PHP version error. (due to it was using PHP 7.4, but now its PHP 8x.) Is there a way, to either point WordPress to the 7.4 version, or uninstall 8x, and install 7.4. or something? I hope there is a way, without rebuilding from scratch.
I found this info, but is this permanent and will it fix my website?
Method 1:
sudo update-alternatives --config php 
sudo update-alternatives --config phar 
sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar 
sudo service apache2 restart 

Method 2: If you want to change PHP 5.6 to 7.4 just run the below commands.
sudo a2dismod php5.6 
sudo a2enmod php7.4 
sudo service apache2 restart –


i found this info... but is this perm. and will it fix my website.
Method 1
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo update-alternatives --config phar
sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar
sudo service apache2 restart
Method 2
If you want to change PHP 5.6 to 7.4 just run the below codes.
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart

Please edit your question to show us the exact, complete php version errors. Well-written php should work with both version 7 and version 8. Are you open to solutions that involve fixing incompatible php code?

Upgrade your WordPress installation!
Wordpress is popular and generally supports the latest PHP version - including PHP8. The fact that it doesn't work suggests that your WordPress installation is old, and likely to have severe security problems.
The solution here is not to downgrade PHP, but to upgrade WordPress to the newest release. WP has a record of security problems that has been exploited, so upgrading is the only sane approach.

While vidarlo's answer is generally correct, the way to go about fixing the issue is:

Downgrading to PHP 7.4
Upgrading the running instance of Wordpress
Upgrading to PHP 8.0.

Method #2 is generally valid to change the PHP version used by Apache (which is enough for the purpose of getting the Wordpress instance to run, although the commands you posted reference PHP 5.6 while you should be addressing PHP 8.0).
As long as PHP 7.4 is still installed (i.e. if
update-alternatives --list php

lists an executable for PHP 7.4), you should be good.
Here's the correct and systemd-specific way to switch back to PHP 7.4:
sudo a2dismod php8.0
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo systemctl restart apache2

After upgrading Wordpress (I warmly suggest backing up the Wordpress installation and disabling all plugins before attempting to upgrade), try and switch back to PHP 8.0:
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.0
sudo systemctl restart apache2

